# somewhere vs someplace vs some place

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

All examples are mine.
I'm curios which of them you consider correct and which not.

**(1a)** *I know somewhere we can go*.
**(1b)** *I know somewhere where we can go*.

**(2a)** *I know someplace we can go*.
**(2b)** *I know someplace where we can go*.

**(3a)** *I know some place we can go to*.
**(3b)** *I know some place where we can go to*.
**(3c)** *I know some place where we can go*.

Comment: _Someplace_ is a specifically American usage. In No. 3, _a place_ would be more idiomatic, and it's unnecessary to include both _where_ and _to_.

Comment: @KateBunting I didn't write (3a) without "_to_": (call it "3d") "_I know some place we can go_." (or which is the same but, as you said, more idiomatic: "_I know a place we can go_.") because I think it's exactly incorrect. But after your comment I began to doubt it. Is (3d) incorrect? Can we really say "_a place we can go_" without "_to_" at the end??? Thanks!

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I meant that (3b), with both _where_ and _to_, was incorrect. _A place we can go_ would be possible, I  think, though rather informal.

Answer (score 0):

In spoken English, you might hear any of these, with a few caveats:

(1b) is awkward because **where** is repeated twice. But you still might hear it.

(2a) and (2b) are American usages because **someplace** is not used outside of the United States (I think).

(3a) - (3c) are non-American usages, but if you add **to** at the end of (2a) and (2b), it's the same question.

While it's generally considered bad form to end a sentence with a preposition, it happens frequently in spoken English. So you wouldn't typically end the sentence with **to** -- and you don't need it -- but you will hear people add it all the time.

In case I didn't answer your question, **somewhere** generally means the same thing as **someplace** (Am) or **some place** (non-Am).

Comment: "_(3a) - (3c) are non-American usages_" - does it mean that (3a), (3b) & (3c) all sound unnatural in the USA?