# When can we omit a preposition at the end of a relative clause?

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses

*a place we can go **to*** - I'm sure it's correct
*a place we can go* - I was told [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319710/somewhere-vs-someplace-vs-some-place?noredirect=1#comment601077_319710) it's possible, though rather informal

(All examples below are mine.)

If it's really possible I'm very curious to conduct research for this topic. I think it's possible probably because we have the word "home" used without "*to*" with the verbs of motion:
"*we can go/get/fly/etc home*" -> "*home we can go/get/fly/etc __*"

I mean:
"*we can go/get/fly/etc to a place*" -> "*a place we can go **to** __*" - the usual variant
but also, by analogy with "*home*":
"*we can go/get/fly/etc to a place*" -> "*a place we can go __*" - one more variant

**(1a)** *The town we are flying **to** for our honeymoon is one of the oldest in the world*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*to*"
**(1b)** *The town we are flying for our honeymoon is one of the oldest in the world*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*to*")

---

By the same analogy, consider the verbs of motion that use "*at*" :
"*we arrived/etc (at) home*" -> "*home we arrived/etc (at) __*"

**(2a)** *The station we arrived **at** was full of people*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*at*"
**(2b)** *The station we arrived was full of people*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*at*")

**(3a)** *The station our train has arrived **at** is full of people*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*at*"
**(3b)** *The station our train has arrived is full of people*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*at*")

---

By the same analogy, consider the verbs of "quiescence" that use "*at*" :
"*we are/sit/stay/etc (at) home*" -> "*home we are/sit/stay/etc (at) __*"

**(4a)** *The hotel we are staying **at** has five stars*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*at*"
**(4b)** *The hotel we are staying has five stars*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*at*")

**(5a)** *I know the owner of the restaurant you were **at** yesterday*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*at*"
**(5b)** *I know the owner of the restaurant you were yesterday*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*at*")

**(6a)** *The hall we are **at** is the hall of fame of our football club*. - I'm sure it's correct with "*at*"
**(6b)** *The hall we are is the hall of fame of our football club*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct without "*at*")

---

So could you check my b-variants and support my reseach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omission of “that” (in this text)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/omission-of-that-in-this-text)

Comment: @BillJ O_O . No. I cannot understand why you offered it.

Comment: Your question is about: be **at** a place **versus** go **to** a place.  And how those prepositions can be positioned in several places and why.

Comment: @Loviii I don't know how that happened. Obviously a glitch in the system.

Answer (score 4):

(1b) is not correct because you are not going to fly the town! You have to say either

> The town we are flying to...

or

> The town where/to which we are flying...

None of your (b) variants makes sense. You didn't arrive the station or stay the hotel, and you weren't the restaurant! The only reason that I suggested that *a place we can go* might possibly be acceptable was because of the idiom *to go places* (though that is usually used metaphorically).

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky. "Go" and most other verbs of motion—including "fly", "travel", and "arrive"—*normally* require a preposition to specify the destination. The following are ungrammatical:

- *We went the town for lunch.
- *We traveled my friend's house.
- *the town we went for lunch
- *the house we arrived

But there are certain expressions where the preposition is not required.

1. "place to go (to)"; "go places": the preposition is optional. *That's a popular place to go.* But: **Let's go a popular place.*
2. "home" does not require "to": *We are traveling home.*
3. "here", "there", "somewhere", "someplace", "anywhere", "nowhere", etc. can take the place of a prepositional phrase, especially in colloquial language.

   - Let's travel somewhere warm.
   - Did they go anywhere?

(Some verbs, like "enter", "reach", and "visit", do not take "to": *They entered the town*, not **They entered to the town*.)